# Replacing multiple lines by one in websites files: bash ? python?

Tags: php, python, bash, sed

I am looking for a command line solution to replace a potentially dangerous string in php files by a safer one, on a Linux server. I'd like to conduct the replace in all hosted sites, and then have it run as a daily cronjob to be on the safer side.
Bash or PHP would be perfect I guess, but I'm ok with Python if that's more efficient.
I could find many examples but could not adapt them to my case, which is

- scan all /httpdocs/ subdirectories in /home/vhosts/(sitename)/ but scanning all files in /home/vhosts will do too.
- determine if there's a file containing a multiple-lines code, ie

`$authsites = array (
    'flickr.com',
    'picasa.com',
    'blah.com',
);`

and if so replace it (sed ?) with

```
$authsites = array ();
```

and log where it replaced it.

Help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Truthfully? If it's a cron job, I'd write it in whichever language you're comfortable with. The end result is the same. Personally, I'd probably avoid awk - it is a powerful tool, but it's based on delimiters and your client code may not always match. You don't want to miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

i use command line perl for bulk search and replace

```
perl -pi -e 's/FIND IT/REPLACE IT' /home/name/public_html/html/*.html
```

Comment: Can the FIND IT be my multiple line code:

$allowedSites = array (
'flickr.com',
'picasa.com',
'blogger.com',
'wordpress.com',
'img.youtube.com',
'upload.wikimedia.org',
);

? (well the editor removes line breaks but this goes over 8 lines)

Answer (score 0):

How about this `awk` one-liner. You can use it with `find` or `for loop` to do mass substitution.

```
awk '/\$authsites/{sub(/\(.*\)/,"( )");print;next}1' INPUTFILE
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file00
$authsites = array ( 'flickr.com', 'picasa.com', 'blah.com', );
$authsites = array ( 'flickr.com', 'aaaa.com', 'blah.com', );
fefe
efef
$authsites = array ( 'flickr.com', 'picasa.com', );

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/\$authsites/{sub(/\(.*\)/,"( )");print;next}1' file00
$authsites = array ( );
$authsites = array ( );
fefe
efef
$authsites = array ( );
```

A `for loop` like this could work (though there may be better ways)

*You can change the name according to your files*

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name "file*" -exec grep -H "\$authsites" {} \;| cut -d":" -f1 | uniq); do awk '/\$authsites/{sub(/\(.*\)/,"( )");print;next}1' $i > $i.new; done
```

Comment: Not sure what the filename can be so I'll have to search them all:
-type f -name "*" ?
Can the grep in "\$authsites" be my multiple line code ?

Comment: you can do `grep -HE "\$authsites|\$allowedSites|\$something"` for searching different code lines. `-E` is extended regex and `|` is `or` notation. You will also have to add those same values in `awk` script. `awk '/\$authsites|\$allowedSites|\$something/`

Comment: I would still write down all possible strings and do a trial with some for the first pass. If everything looks ok (you can do code compare) then add all remaining substitutions and run it. Your original code won't be affected since all changes goes to a new file when we do `$i > $i.new`. This gives you the flexibility to delete all `.new` files and start over again.